# Backing up i.imgur.com images that may be at risk due to their new ToS

Tags: discussion, images

Now, you should be using the "add picture" feature in the editor to get an i.stack.imgur.com address for your images in your posts. That is hosting that SE pays for and images there won't get deleted. However, we have some posts that use free hosting, namely i.imgur.com. On May 15th, Imgur is [changing their ToS](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/14415587638029-Imgur-Terms-of-Service-Update-April-19-2023-) and will be "removing old, unused, and inactive content that is not tied to a user account" which may include some of our images on free hosting. (See [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388556/323179) for more details.)

I came up with a plan to back up every single one of these images without bumping too many posts in a short time: we upload all these links on meta. I explain a bit more about this in my [answer on SFF Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13901/82909).

Using a series of queries ([returning one image](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/revision/1743757/2119851/top-posts-with-non-stack-imgur-images-order-by-of-views), [returning two images](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/edit/1743757#resultSets)), I made this quick and slightly dirty table, which we can use if any of the images break.

Did I miss anything? Does anyone have any questions? (I don't have a question.)

(Reposted on [ELL meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5890/41273) but for the images in their posts.)

---

| Post Link | url | number | new URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| What distinguishes a predicative complement from an object? | /i.imgur.com/bDeZ7K3_d.j | 1 | manually fixed |
| Term for "[Idiom], [Rhyme]" like "See you later, alligator." | /i.imgur.com/b52cBMo.png | 1 | [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL9dP.png) |
| What is the difference between Ukraine and the Ukraine? | /i.imgur.com/KzoLSE8.png | 1 | [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxb5s.png) |
| You can’t have your cake and eat it too | /i.imgur.com/MbSZ4i0.png | 1 | [7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYXns.png) |
| Ear lies or ear sits? | /i.imgur.com/sFUPgfS.png | 1 | [8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdNqT.png) |
| Complex sentence whose subject is a clause | /i.imgur.com/dgLQJDU.png | 1 | [9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDq2o.png) |
| "To science the sh*t out of something" | /i.imgur.com/yMaUsIz.png | 1 | [10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCKGP.png) |
| What is the word for this type of pawn or figurine? | /i.imgur.com/RRzFHh5.jpg | 1 | [11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDLTJ.jpg) |
| Is the adjective "abject" ever found with any word other than "poverty"? Does it mean something other than "very" or "utterly"? | /i.imgur.com/0KgoI.png" | 1 | [12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9skdK.png) |
| crawl in a hole and pull it in after me | /i.imgur.com/y63XmYv.jpg | 1 | [13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noK3t.jpg) |
| Is there another way to refer to the "proximal interphalangeal joints"? | /i.imgur.com/18YF7Di.png | 1 | [14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53DSv.png) |
| What's this "Jl. Sg." appended to a name in the Social Register? | /i.imgur.com/eOPCh4K.jpg | 1 | [15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1GlK.jpg) |
| How macabre is a graveyard? | /i.imgur.com/OaV03qT.png | 1 | [16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57D5I.jpg) |
| What does 'TL;DR' mean and how is it used? | /i.imgur.com/xaYZ6C2.jpg | 1 | [17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS7Qv.jpg) |
| Is there a list and/or a rule for nouns that must be pluralized when not preceded by a definite article or adjective? | /i.imgur.com/LIQVuNc.jpg | 1 | [18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nq7q.jpg) |
| What's the origin of the phrase "fatal dower"? | /i.imgur.com/aVvqEqR.png | 1 | [19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0sVW.png) |
| Connotation and etymology of "dossier" | /i.imgur.com/a9JITOO.png | 1 | [20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAtu7.png) |
| Can one meet criteria, or satisfy requirements? | /i.imgur.com/1kWMinT.png | 1 | [21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRDDm.png) |
| What's the single-word for "left or right handed"? | /i.imgur.com/gRk1uZm.gif | 1 | [22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHhsQ.gif) |
| "Best believe..." as a rhetorical device or device of storytelling | /i.imgur.com/I71Hik0.png | 1 | [23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4iDL.jpg) |
| Is there a term for a free ride without consent? | /i.imgur.com/BUawS5f.png | 1 | [24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkYSE.png) |
| How can I practice differentiating between the /æ/ and /ɛ/ sounds in English phonology? | /i.imgur.com/mez3U.png" | 1 | [25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqOtW.png) |
| Is “have went” gaining common currency in AmE and BrE? | /i.imgur.com/3EM8YRw.png | 1 | [26](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDQCs.png) |
| Once/twice/thrice vs one/two/three times | /i.imgur.com/qw844.png"> | 1 | [27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cup8Q.png) |
| A more general version of "projecting" | /i.imgur.com/jUH23.jpg" | 1 | [28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEvSW.jpg) |
| Word to describe "beautiful but worthless" | /i.imgur.com/JIx2mML.png | 1 | [29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtqsV.png) |
| What's this part of the nose called? | /i.imgur.com/eSb7wxv.jpg | 1 | [30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Bi7.jpg) |
| Is factoid an Auto-antonym? | /i.imgur.com/A26TlWf.png | 1 | [31](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DWPD.png) |
| Explanation of a phrase | /i.imgur.com/Uak4YU3.gif | 1 | video won't upload ([backup link](https://www.reddit.com/r/educationalgifs/comments/96r7xw/river_meandering_and_formation_of_oxbow_lakes/)) |
| Is there a more generic word for "space objects" (not counting human-made or massive objects)? | /i.imgur.com/SoH4uk6.png | 1 | [33](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV4tE.png) |
| Is there such a thing as a sentence sign? | /i.imgur.com/5xK11qn.png | 1 | [34](https://i.stack.imgur.com/folL9.png) |
| "Hard disk" vs. "Hard drive" vs. "Hard disk drive" | /i.imgur.com/QZZjcOd.png | 1 | [35](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjVfv.png) |
| "Hard disk" vs. "Hard drive" vs. "Hard disk drive" | /i.imgur.com/KIG8qWX.png | 1 | [36](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyaxQ.png) |
| Open non-compositional compound nouns | /i.imgur.com/2LLjieX.jpg | 1 | [37](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z9XO.jpg) |
| Is wisest here an adjective or noun? | /i.imgur.com/HNEczwd.png | 1 | [38](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go4s0.png) |
| Ambiguous syntax tree and phrase structure rules | /i.imgur.com/ShMtNEy.png | 1 | [39](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF9o5.png) |
| Is there a term for when visual negative-space and positive-space are switched | /i.imgur.com/eXr9rNa.gif | 1 | [40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4raz.gif) |
| Single word for old and many-times-seen content | /i.imgur.com/YPN71TN.jpg | 1 | [41](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMyfb.jpg) |
| Third person singular verb for plural noun? | /i.imgur.com/BXUIAQ2.jpg | 1 | [42](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro5px.jpg) |
| Alphabetic analogue of Numero sign (№)? | /i.imgur.com/7KxUaom.png | 1 | [43](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhvUK.png) |
| Handwriting is to illegible as drawing is to what? | /i.imgur.com/RWZzg0g.jpg | 1 | [44](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsXLC.jpg) |
| When does something qualify as 'gore', is there a cut-off? | /i.imgur.com/so5ur53.jpg | 1 | [45](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufpRO.jpg) (Warning: gore) |
| When can an embedded interrogative clause exhibit Subject-Auxiliary Inversion? | /i.imgur.com/iA3XH6g.jpg | 1 | [46](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J8VO.jpg) |
| Do any exclamative sentences admit Subject-Auxiliary Inversion? | /i.imgur.com/d3BiCoW.jpg | 1 | [47](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlkFA.jpg) |
| A question about constructing relatives from existential sentences | /i.imgur.com/CWhVnA0.jpg | 1 | [48](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py65g.jpg) |
| To start in or at a company? | /i.imgur.com/3sexHri.jpg /i.imgur.com/f6kITXi.jpg | 2 | [49](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv4Ux.jpg) [50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDtsq.jpg) |
| What is the word that denotes the words preceding these nouns? | /i.imgur.com/GwE8N5I.png /i.imgur.com/GwE8N5I.png | 2 | [51](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrsxf.png) |
| Food Rhyme with No | /i.imgur.com/v6xg7.jpg" /i.imgur.com/v6xg7.jpg</ | 2 | [52](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wgjK.jpg) |
| Term to describe 'all the rest' of a collection of things? | /i.imgur.com/Ll9yp7P.png /i.imgur.com/Ll9yp7P.png | 2 | [53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG7II.png) |
| Term for a method used in solving equations | /i.imgur.com/zHvLD27.gif /i.imgur.com/tkyTznS.gif | 2 | [54](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAsh3.gif) [55](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaAU9.gif) |
| "The past hours" or "The passed hours" which one to use? | /i.imgur.com/QKyKDSS.png /i.imgur.com/QKyKDSS.png | 2 | [56](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Vjs.png) |
| Is there a word or a special phrase in English to describe the curvy upper lip that some people like Rio Ferdinand have? | /i.imgur.com/Eypgwyc.jpg /i.imgur.com/cFAVzE4.jpg | 2 | [57](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fN87.jpg) [58](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDTac.jpg) |
| What is the difference between "emoji" and "emoticon"? | /i.imgur.com/qfa2sU7.png /i.imgur.com/8T4JGA7.png | 2 | [59](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BW63.png) [60](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QU2c.png) |
| Usage of 'Ohh stop it, you!' | /i.imgur.com/eGtLLO8.jpg /i.imgur.com/eGtLLO8.jpg | 2 | [61](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi9ak.jpg) |
| Where and why were capital letters first used in headlines? | /i.imgur.com/m7Fl51E.jpg /i.imgur.com/pSSC6hz.png | 2 | [62](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6a44.jpg) [63](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ThUU.png) |
| English translation for Kockásfülű Nyúl (Hungarian) | /i.imgur.com/Ui3wsND.jpg /i.imgur.com/Ui3wsND.jpg | 2 | [64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJNZP.jpg) |
| What is the opposite of acidic? | /i.imgur.com/tqQmJh8.png /i.imgur.com/tqQmJh8.png | 2 | [65](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hNCr.png) |
| Wording: closest date vs nearest date? | /i.imgur.com/fV0negC.png /i.imgur.com/45ygsNb.png | 2 | [66](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t5lC.png) [67](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVti0.png) |
| Why are 'blueish' and 'bluish' both considered correct spellings? | /i.imgur.com/xvVbc.png" /i.imgur.com/69Ccm.png" | 2 | [68](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdUrq.png) [69](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rkzS.png) |
| Colloquial meaning of 'exponential decrease' | /i.imgur.com/VaouBye.gif /i.imgur.com/6lRpKQF.gif | 2 | [70](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N43sY.gif) [71](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDg2b.gif) |
| Alternative expression/term to trivial use of 'OCD' | /i.imgur.com/SuZQUWF.jpg /i.imgur.com/VMpAW.jpg" | 2 | [72](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl6ii.jpg) [73](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XDuI.jpg) |
| How is this sentence to be interpreted? | /i.imgur.com/hPLXDrK.jpg /i.imgur.com/hPLXDrK.jpg | 2 | [74](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciDDD.jpg) |
| Were there any other synonyms to "sustainability" before the 80s? | /i.imgur.com/79sPNjH.png /i.imgur.com/Hhkzkrf.png | 2 | [75](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiRUu.png) [76](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Liw.png) |
| How does 'bear off' explain the etymology of 'berth'? | /i.imgur.com/Zmmj7AI.jpg /i.imgur.com/Zmmj7AI.jpg | 2 | [77](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OabFM.jpg) |
| A person that shows officials where to go | /i.imgur.com/uDTCZlP.gif /i.imgur.com/uDTCZlP.gif | 2 | GIF won't upload, but has 35k views so is hopefully popular enough. See [President Elect Donald Trump leaving the Lamington Presbyterian Church in Bedminster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtr5s.jpg) |
| Are there any style guides that dictate the use of "on/at Amazon" (and other web platforms). If so, what are they and what's the reasoning behind it? | /i.imgur.com/jXW9b7G.jpg | 3 | manually fixed |
| A word for a squared layout of differently shaped objects | /i.imgur.com/cWkfeAPm.jp | 4 | manually fixed |
| The curious case of "These following + a plural" vs "The following + a plural" | /i.imgur.com/U9joyBJ.png | 4 | manually fixed |
| What is the correct relative pronoun for "government"? | /i.imgur.com/uhz7G5B.jpg | 7 | manually fixed |
| "To the extent of" in this context | /imgur.com/a/soCajqB" | 1 | [78](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgQUG.png) |
| Site hopping, non-related subjects, wasting time on the internet | /imgur.com/zoWpqEB | 1 | long, popular video |
| "Best believe..." as a rhetorical device or device of storytelling | /imgur.com/gallery/JfDXi | 1 | popular gallery |
| How do you use "i.e." in a sentence? | /imgur.com/IRoTb.png | 1 | [79](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3x4L.png) |
| Name for the specific advertisement stands | /imgur.com/a/DaSYA | 1 | [80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKcjm.jpg) [81](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aSsy.png) |
| IELTS Reading True/False/Not given question | /imgur.com/dV34Hlk | 1 | [82](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wbIr.jpg) |
| Is a comma the correct punctuation in "Help a thief?" | /imgur.com/yWoO0pw | 1 | [83](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5jJ1.jpg) |
| Is this proper usage of "through which?" How can I best construct this sentence? | /imgur.com/a/Fu4yy | 2 | [84](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU7bZ.jpg) |
| Why is an article present here? | /imgur.com/lAT2V8x | 2 | [85](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0VnD.png) |
| How to call different types of grid/tilemap with (1+ words or sentence)? | /imgur.com/gallery/rPZIE | 2 | user-owned gallery |
| Is "purchased" more formal than "bought?" | /imgur.com/IEO1D2e | 2 | [86](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymEx7.png) |
| Punctuation for quote reversal | /imgur.com/c0J95 | 2 | [87](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqjM4.png) |
| What is the blurring of pixels for fidelity called? | /imgur.com/a/gRXPJ - | 2 | images of [this pdf](https://johanneskopf.de/publications/pixelart/paper/pixel.pdf) |
| Warmth of a seat that has been vacated by a person who was sitting on it | /imgur.com/gallery/foIrR | 2 | attribution link |
| Name for a street that goes through the green area | /imgur.com/2DCwEpW | 2 | [89](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLdHz.jpg) |
| Term for video artifact of blocky grey visuals | /imgur.com/a/oZkQwm4 | 2 | [90](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGecB.png) (only really needs the one image) |
| What is "gonna transfer in" means? | /imgur.com/uN1qfvP | 2 | [91](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srDIj.jpg) |
| final though-tag: That tongue at the end tho; That victory dance though | /imgur.com/gallery/fI13J /imgur.com/gallery/VwZCZ | 2 | links to comments |
| Same theme pictures( or paintings) merged | /imgur.com/RGlu2jM | 2 | [92](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBK3a.jpg) |
| Logical term for when an object is the same thing as itself | /imgur.com/KmUUV09 | 2 | [93](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FXei.png) |
| Expression for a very specific utility post climbing gear called "maneas"/"pretal" in spanish, widely used in South America | /imgur.com/q8liy3D /imgur.com/xTGFzVj | 2 | [94](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6ml7.jpg) [95](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgrpo.png) |

Comment: I imagine that comments are toasted, right?

Comment: @Braiam I've only backed up images from posts and I wasn't planning to do comments. It's a tricky situation, since editing comments is high effort (since only mods can do it) and often low reward (since they are so often used for jokes instead of something that is essential to the question). If someone wants to volunteer to back up comment images, give me an idea of how many there are and I'll tell you how many comments I'd be willing to edit.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally there would be a way for mods to edit old posts without bumping them. I wonder if SE might consider adding such a feature for this sort of bulk operation.